# Using cursor to loop in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have written SQL code below to return the following result set. This code allows a user to select a DataLibrary (Parent) and find its underlying DataLibraries (child).

```
Classification || DLGroup || DataLibraryName || Usedby || EntityName || SubEntityName
InUse          || MO      || SingleorAll     || MDL    || DashboardA ||
InUse          || MO      || SingleorAll     || MDL    || DashboardB ||
InUse          || MO      || SingleorAll     || MDL    || DashboardC ||


-- Begin Code --
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @SelectedDL VARCHAR(50)

SET @SelectedDL = '1264' 

--BEGIN TRY 
--CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20130828-063538] ON [dbo].[tblrpt_view] 
--( 
-- [view_type_id] ASC 
--) 
--END TRY 
--BEGIN CATCH 
-- ALREADY THERE 
--END CATCH 

DECLARE @PPTReports TABLE ( 
rpt_id INTEGER 
) 

INSERT INTO @PPTReports 
SELECT RPT.rpt_id 
FROM dbo.tblrpt_main RPT 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_view V 
ON V.rpt_id = RPT.rpt_id 
AND V.view_type_id = 1999 


IF IsNull(@SelectedDL,'') = '' SET @SelectedDL = '0' 

SELECT 'In Use' as Classification, 
DLG.group_name as DLGroup, 
DL.datasource_name as DataLibraryName, 
'Report' as UsedBy, 
R.rpt_name as EntityName, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),'') AS SubEntityName 
FROM dbo.tblrpt_datascript DL 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript_group DLG 
ON DLG.d_group_id = DL.datascript_group 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_main R 
ON R.rpt_data_source = DL.datasource_id 
WHERE (DL.datasource_id = @SelectedDL 
OR @SelectedDL = '0') 
UNION 
SELECT 'In Use' as Classification, 
DLG.group_name, 
DL.datasource_name as DataLibraryName, 
'Legacy Chart' as Category, 
R.rpt_name as EntityName, 
C.control_name as SubEntityName 
FROM dbo.tblrpt_datascript DL 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript_group DLG 
ON DLG.d_group_id = DL.datascript_group 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_chart C 
ON C.datasource_id = DL.datasource_id 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_main R 
ON R.rpt_id = C.rpt_id 
WHERE (DL.datasource_id = @SelectedDL 
OR @SelectedDL = '0') 
UNION 
SELECT 'In Use' as Classification, 
DLG.group_name, 
DL.datasource_name as DataLibraryName, 
'Merge Data Library' as Category, 
MDL.datasource_name as EntityName, 
'' as SubEntityName 
FROM dbo.tblrpt_datascript DL 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript_group DLG 
ON DLG.d_group_id = DL.datascript_group 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript MDL 
ON MDL.datalibraryXML LIKE '%<DataLibaryId>'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,DL.datasource_id)+'</DataLibaryId>%' 
WHERE (DL.datasource_id = @SelectedDL 
OR @SelectedDL = '0') 
UNION 
SELECT 'In Use' as Classification, 
DLG.group_name, 
DL.datasource_name as DataLibraryName, 
'Prevalidation' as Category, 
PV.name as EntityName, 
'' as SubEntityName 
FROM dbo.tblrpt_datascript DL 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript_group DLG 
ON DLG.d_group_id = DL.datascript_group 
JOIN dbo.prevalidators PV 
ON PV.datasourceId = DL.datasource_id 
WHERE (DL.datasource_id = @SelectedDL 
OR @SelectedDL = '0') 
UNION 
SELECT 'In Use' as Classification, 
DLG.group_name, 
DL.datasource_name as DataLibraryName, 
'Matrix' as Category, 
WFQ.data_event_name as EntityName, 
'' as SubEntityName 
FROM dbo.tblrpt_datascript DL 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript_group DLG 
ON DLG.d_group_id = DL.datascript_group 
JOIN dbo.workflow_data_events WFQ 
ON WFQ.datasource_id = DL.datasource_id 
WHERE (DL.datasource_id = @SelectedDL 
OR @SelectedDL = '0') 
UNION 
SELECT 'In Use' as Classification, 
DLG.group_name, 
DL.datasource_name as DataLibraryName, 
'Commentary Template' as Category, 
COM.template_name as EntityName, 
'' as SubEntityName 
FROM dbo.tblrpt_datascript DL 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript_group DLG 
ON DLG.d_group_id = DL.datascript_group 
JOIN dbo.commentary_template COM 
ON COM.datalibrary_id = DL.datasource_id 
WHERE (DL.datasource_id = @SelectedDL 
OR @SelectedDL = '0') 
UNION 
SELECT 'In Use' as Classification, 
DLG.group_name, 
DL.datasource_name as DataLibraryName, 
'Financial Control' as Category, 
C.name as EntityName, 
'' as SubEntityName 
FROM dbo.tblrpt_datascript DL 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript_group DLG 
ON DLG.d_group_id = DL.datascript_group 
JOIN dbo.financial_controls_data_source DS 
ON DS.datasource_id = DL.datasource_id 
JOIN dbo.financial_controls C 
ON C.id = DS.financial_control_id 
WHERE (DL.datasource_id = @SelectedDL 
OR @SelectedDL = '0') 
UNION 
SELECT 'In Use' as Classification, 
DLG.group_name, 
DL.datasource_name as DataLibraryName, 
'PPT Child DL' as Category, 
RPT.rpt_name as EntityName, 
'' as SubEntityName 
FROM @PPTReports TMP 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_main RPT 
ON RPT.rpt_id = TMP.rpt_id 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_view V 
ON V.rpt_id = RPT.rpt_id 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript DL 
ON DL.datasource_id != RPT.rpt_data_source 
AND SUBSTRING(V.custom_mechanism_xml,1,2000) LIKE '%<DlName>'+ DL.datasource_name+'</DlName>%' 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript_group DLG 
ON DLG.d_group_id = DL.datascript_group 
WHERE 
(DL.datasource_id = @SelectedDL 
OR @SelectedDL = '0') 
UNION 
SELECT 'NOT Used', 
DLG.group_name, 
DL.datasource_name, 
'' as Category, 
'' as EntityName, 
'' as SubEntityName 
FROM dbo.tblrpt_datascript DL 
JOIN dbo.tblrpt_datascript_group DLG 
ON DLG.d_group_id = DL.datascript_group 
WHERE (DL.datasource_id = @SelectedDL 
OR @SelectedDL = '0') 
AND NOT EXISTS ( 
(SELECT 1 from dbo.tblrpt_main R WHERE R.rpt_data_source = DL.datasource_id) 
UNION 
(SELECT 1 from dbo.financial_controls_data_source FC WHERE FC.datasource_id = DL.datasource_id) 
UNION 
(SELECT 1 from dbo.tblrpt_chart C WHERE C.datasource_id = DL.datasource_id) 
UNION 
(SELECT 1 from dbo.prevalidators PV WHERE PV.datasourceId = DL.datasource_id) 
UNION 
(SELECT 1 from dbo.commentary_template COM WHERE COM.datalibrary_id = DL.datasource_id) 
UNION 
(SELECT 1 from dbo.tblrpt_datascript MDL WHERE MDL.datalibraryXML LIKE '%<DataLibaryId>'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,DL.datasource_id)+'</DataLibaryId>%') 
UNION 
(SELECT 1 from dbo.tblrpt_view VV JOIN @PPTReports PP ON PP.rpt_id = VV.rpt_id AND SUBSTRING(VV.custom_mechanism_xml,1,2000) LIKE '%<DlName>'+ DL.datasource_name+'</DlName>%') 
) 
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6 

-- End Code --
```

I would like to take this a step further and have three levels: Parent DL, Child DL, SUB DL of the Child DL. I think cursor is the best way to keep looping until it cannot find another Data Library, but I am unsure how to write the code. Below is what I would like for data to look:

```
DataLibraryName     ||      Parent
SingleOrAll         ||      DashboardA
SingleOrAll         ||      DashboardB
SingleOrAll         ||      DashboardC
DashboardA          ||      CountryA
DashboardA          ||      CountryB
DashboardB          ||      ContinentU
DashboardC          ||      Atlantic1
DashboardC          ||      Pacific3
DashboardC          ||      China1
```

Please help

Comment: No, Cursors are usually NOT the best way of looping in any database language.  That's usually the last resort when joins won't do.

Comment: Please, don't use loop. Learn proper SQL.

Comment: Search for Recursive Common Table Expressions (CTEs) and parent/child relationships for a better solution to this kind of query.

Comment: Greenspark, would you be able to help by kick starting the CTE code? This would provide a framework to my solution. Thanks in advance.